# HTML5 validation and adding custom string comparison

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML 5 validation that works fine but I now need to add some custom validation to it to check if 2 input elements have the same value.  But so far it just gets ignored.  Here is my code, with the changes that don't work commented :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //set up buttons
        $(function () {
            $("input:submit").button();
        });
    });
</script>    

<!--IE doesn't support setCustomValidity--> 
<![if !IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //set up buttons
        $(function () {
            $("input:submit").button();
        });

        //added to compare Name and Email Address
        var name = $("#Name").val();
        var emailAddress = $("#EmailAddress").val();

        if ((name == emailAddress) && (name != "")) {
            $("#Name").setCustomValidity("Name must not be equal to Email Address");
            return false;
        }

        var elementsInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var elementsTextArea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

        for (var i = 0; i < elementsInput.length; i++) {

            elementsInput[i].oninvalid = function (e) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("");
                if (!e.target.validity.valid) {

                    switch (e.target.name) {

                        case "Name":
                            e.target.setCustomValidity("@Html.Raw(Resources.Validation.FullNameRequired)");
                            break;

                        case "EmailAddress":
                            //e.preventDefault();

                            //later you decide you want to submit
                            //$(this).unbind('submit').submit();

                            if (e.target.validity.valueMissing) {
                                e.target.setCustomValidity("@Html.Raw(Resources.Validation.EmailAddressRequired)");
                            }
                            else if (e.target.validity.patternMismatch) {
                                e.target.setCustomValidity("@Html.Raw(Resources.Validation.EmailAddressInvalid)");
                            }
                            break;

                        case "PhoneNumber":
                            //e.preventDefault();
                            if (e.target.validity.valueMissing) {
                                e.target.setCustomValidity("@Html.Raw(Resources.Validation.PhoneNumberRequired)");
                            }
                            else if (e.target.validity.patternMismatch) {
                                e.target.setCustomValidity("@Html.Raw(Resources.Validation.PhoneNumberInvalid)");
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
            };
                elementsInput[i].oninput = function (e) {
                    e.target.setCustomValidity("");
                };
            }

        for (var j = 0; j < elementsTextArea.length; j++) {
            elementsTextArea[j].oninvalid = function (e) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("");
                if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                    switch (e.target.name) {
                        case "Details":
                            e.target.setCustomValidity("@Html.Raw(Resources.Validation.DetailsRequired)");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
            elementsTextArea[j].oninput = function (e) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            };
        }
    });

</script>
<![endif]>
```

Comment: Small note: You can do valid downlevel-reveal conditional comments like so: `<!--[if !IE]>-->...<!--<![endif]-->`

Comment: Just a note: it's always possible to get around custom client-side JavaScript validation by disabling JavaScript in the browser and/or using a browser that doesn't support HTML5 form validation, so if this is going into production you should probably also re-validate everything on the server.

Comment: Hey, why can't my name be equal to my email address? ;-)